# Padding an image in Bootstrap with background colour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

Couldn't find an answer to this so..

It's probably a very simple solution but I've been tunnel visioning for the past 20 minutes and it's frustrating me.

The padding of an image, which I'm trying to give a circle background element, is really annoying.

Margin doesn't work either.

My image is 120 px large, and the padding of 2em just makes it smaller, but I want it to stay the same size, but have a bigger background size.

Here's the code:

```
    <div class="row">
    </div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-4 img-icon-pad">
            <img src="img/icons/html.png" class="img-responsive img-icons" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/icons/html.png" class="img-responsive img-icons" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/icons/html.png" class="img-responsive img-icons" />
        </div>

    </div>

    /* Boxes */

.img-icons {
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #f8f8ec;
    border: 2px solid #e97117;
    padding: 2em;
border-radius: 50%;

}

.img-icon-pad {
}
```

And a screenshot of what I mean:

- No padding
  https://i.gyazo.com/745896ad418274f70e8189f6b84c7b6d.png
- Padding: 
  https://i.gyazo.com/b2a264d8a361a426cc43992d90352e79.png

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to achieve padding without the image being cut off by it.

Comment: you haven't set a border radius, therefore the padding is square, thus cutting off your image

Comment: If you looked at the screenshot, you would have noticed I do have a border radius.

Comment: It would help justify what you said above if you included your complete css then, because there is no border radius present there sir.

Comment: Could you replicate your problem with a JSFiddle, the answers provided below should suffice to fix the problem, you may be overlooking something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is ok

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <div class="thumbnail">
               <img src="img/icons/html.png" class="img-responsive img-icons" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/icons/html.png" class="img-responsive img-icons" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/icons/html.png" class="img-responsive img-icons" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <style>
.thumbnail {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #e97117;
    background-color: #f8f8ec;
     padding: 2em;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you increase the height of .img-icons class from 120 to 150px or bigger if you want.
If that doesn't work then you have probably restricted size of the div containing the img.

Comment: Yup that doesn't work, how do I edit the div settings? I'm using Bootstrap so

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what are you trying to do :

```
<div class="row">



        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="img-responsive img-icons" >
          <div class="img">

          </div>
        </div>
        </div>



    </div>
```

css:

```
.img-icons {
    height: 120px;
    width:120px;
    background-color: #f8f8ec;
    border: 2px solid #e97117;
   border-radius: 50%;
 padding: 2em;
}
.img{
  text-align:center;
   height:120px;
   width:120px;
     background-color: #f8f8ec;
    border: 2px solid #e97117;
}
```

you can see the result here https://jsfiddle.net/nt0zqc1t/3/

Comment: That doesn't really change anything

Comment: you are trying to create a rounded background with a rectangle img inside right ? increase the padding to 3em to get the looking https://jsfiddle.net/nt0zqc1t/3/

Comment: you should give the padding to the container of the img not the img

Comment: With your fiddle, this happens https://i.gyazo.com/0c2ec6bbcd0bee9bb41edf2eeb8940e9.png

Comment: are setting  box-sizing: border-box;  if so pleas add  box-sizing: content-box;

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say that in .img-icons class you have width set to auto.  This may be causing resizing.  If you set it to a fixed width it may not resize.

Comment: Width is set to auto in .img-icons

Comment: the auto width is causing the re-scaling @AnneKok

Comment: Changing the width to a fixed width does not change anything. Auto width same story.